# android - make interactive vector drawable or view from svg

Tags: android, svg, android-custom-view, interactive, xml-drawable

**Requirement:**
I have an irregular shaped svg, the svg have several many elements that are supposed to be interactive like changing colors and adding click listeners etc.

**Problem:** I need a way to convert this svg to regular android view or somehow use the svg to assign ID's to portions so they may be dealt as regular views. It should also support pinch to zoom and scrolling.

**Sample Shape:**

[image: this sample is only made for demo purposes, actual svg is more irregular in nature]

Comment: I only have the svg with me yet

Comment: I couldnt understand that example code well, so I thought I might write a custom view or create a layout instead, but I am still stuck. so I am still at svg phase.

Comment: So, to understand that class I really need first have a familiarity with Shape class because I couldn't grab the logic out of code itself.

I mean, I could have just copy and pasted the code but I really don't wanna use something I dont fully understand, so thought I might hunt for some workarounds

p.s. I am really not an expert at shapes, drawables and svg themselves, pardon

Comment: went to sleep last night, will give it a try and get back to for sure...Thanks for the help

Comment: just give me one more, I ll make it work...I am confident

Comment: give you what ?

Comment: *one more day...  pardon

Comment: @pskink, So I was able to make the class work, I had to make a few changes to get what I need and the PathParser didnt work out of the box, had to search Android Source code online to add that class..

p.s. it looks really gorgeous, Thanks

Next steps: I still need to make it zoom like a regular pinch to zoom within its bounds and be able to scroll.

Comment: Please add a full answer so I may upvote it

Comment: `PathParser` works out of the box: it has  a static method that parses `String` pathData and returns `Path` object

Comment: I tried search for the class in sdk put there was no PathParser, yet its working well with added source, so I have nothing bad to say about...

Any ideas for zoom and pan, I showing the vectorShape as background of regular View widget

Comment: post your source code you have written so far

Comment: Here you go....https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BxiJIDcszdwZQTk0M1R6dTd4WFk?usp=sharing

Comment: I also tried extending View to ZoomView using link below, but either its not scaling the View background or I haven't implemented it right...

ref:....http://vivin.net/2011/12/04/implementing-pinch-zoom-and-pandrag-in-an-android-view-on-the-canvas/

Comment: So I was able to figure out how to support both pan/zoom and adding shape to view...What I tried to do is instead of extending shape and drawing vector there, I did the same in the zoomable View extended class...you can check the update code here.....https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxiJIDcszdwZQTk0M1R6dTd4WFk....
problem is, zooming and pan is a little chunky and after zooming the layer touch responder give layer according to actual view size and not the scaled one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141382/discussion-between-nouman-tahir-and-pskink).

Comment: @pskink, this is the final code I am using...https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxiJIDcszdwZZHFncW5VWkhUekE/view?usp=sharing
sorry for keeping you on wait...

Comment: most of your code is never used as `ScaleGestureDetector detector` is nowhere called with `ScaleGestureDetector#onTouchEvent` method

Comment: I know, I didn't had to use them as things work well for me without it for now.